# How to input multiple images with flow_from_dataframe in keras?

Tags: python, dataframe, keras

I have been trying to create **Siamese model** for finding image similarity between 2 images (it has 2 input images). At the beginning I tested it with a small dataset, it fitted in my RAM and it worked kinda well. Now, I want to increase the training sample size and in order to do that I created **`images.csv`** file. In this file, I have 3 columns: 
**`image_1`, `image_2`, `similarity`**

**`image_1`** and **`image_2`** are absolute paths to images. `similarity` is either 0 or 1. 

I tried

```
generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe, target_size=(64, 64, 1), x_col=['image_1', 'image_2'],
                                                    y_col='similarity',
                                                    class_mode='sparse', subset='training')
```

but got this error:

> ValueError: All values in column x_col=['image_1', 'image_2'] must be
>   strings.

after removing **image_2** and having **`x_col=image_1`** error disappeared but it has only 1 input image. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @nuric I was able to input multiple images. Here is full code for creating flow:

```
def get_flow_from_dataframe(generator, dataframe,
                            image_shape=(64, 64),
                            subset='training',
                            color_mode='grayscale', batch_size=64):
    train_generator_1 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe, target_size=image_shape,
                                                      color_mode=color_mode,
                                                      x_col='image_1',
                                                      y_col='prediction',
                                                      class_mode='binary',
                                                      shuffle=True,
                                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                                      seed=7,
                                                      subset=subset, drop_duplicates=False)

    train_generator_2 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe, target_size=image_shape,
                                                      color_mode=color_mode,
                                                      x_col='image_2',
                                                      y_col='prediction',
                                                      class_mode='binary',
                                                      shuffle=True,
                                                      batch_size=batch_size,
                                                      seed=7,
                                                      subset=subset, drop_duplicates=False)
    while True:
        x_1 = train_generator_1.next()
        x_2 = train_generator_2.next()

        yield [x_1[0], x_2[0]], x_1[1]
```

Full code of fit_generator:

```
train_gen = get_flow_from_dataframe(generator, dataframe, image_shape=(64, 64),
                                        color_mode='rgb',
                                        batch_size=batch_size)
valid_gen = get_flow_from_dataframe(generator, dataframe, image_shape=(64, 64),
                                        color_mode='rgb',
                                        batch_size=batch_size,
                                        subset='validation')

model.fit_generator(train_gen, epochs=50,
                        steps_per_epoch=step_size,
                        validation_data=valid_gen,
                        validation_steps=step_size,
                        callbacks=get_call_backs('../models/model_1.h5', monitor='val_acc'),
                        )
```

Also as I see memory consumption is huge.

Comment: do you need two parallel cnn for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't flow two images from a single generator using that method, it is designed to handle one, from [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/):

> **x_col:** string, column in dataframe that contains the filenames (or absolute paths if directory is None).

Instead what you can do is create two generators and more appropriately allow your network to have *two inputs*:

```
in1 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe, target_size=(64, 64, 1), x_col='image_1',
                                                    y_col='similarity',
                                                    class_mode='sparse', subset='training')

in2 = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe, target_size=(64, 64, 1), x_col='image_2',
                                                    y_col='similarity',
                                                    class_mode='sparse', subset='training')
```

And then build a model using [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) that accepts two image inputs:

```
input_image1 = Input(shape=(64, 64, 1))
input_image2 = Input(shape=(64, 64, 1))
# ... all other layers to create output_layer
model = Model([input_image1, input_image2], output)
# ...
```

This is more reflective of your model actually having 2 inputs as images.

Comment: And when I apply `fit_generator` should I add 2 flows like this `[in1,  in2]`? Then does this also mean that `seed` for both flows should be equal?

Comment: Hmm, I think you need another generator that combines the flow of the two, here is that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313525/how-do-i-combine-two-keras-generator-functions